# Threading inside a cursor in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I wrote a script in `python` that connects to a database using `psycopg`.
I'm working with two tables in the same database.  First I run a `select * from table_1` and after that I check if each row (`fetchone`) meets some requirements.  If they do, a new row in table_2 is created with an `INSERT`.  The code looks similar to this:

```
cursor_1 = conn.cursor()
cursor_2 = conn.cursor()

cursor_1.execute("SELECT * FROM table_1")
for i in range(1,n):
    a = cursor_1.fetchone()
    if (condition_in_a):
        cursor_2.execute("INSERT into table_2 (f1,f2) values (v1,v2)")
```

The script runs in a sequential `for` loop and I wanted to know if there's a better way to accomplish this task through `psycopg2.pool` in terms of performance.  So my question is: Is it possible to multithread a `psycopg` cursor? If not, what would be the best approach to achieve a better performance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a single-thread approach, you are trying to keep the balance between memory usage and rows processing speed. `fetchone` decrease memory usage but require more work to fetch the data. `fetchall` for huge datasets use large memory amounts and data loading may take some time before processing started.

So, at least, a better way is to fetch data by smaller portions with `fetchmany`. The following generator may simplify a process:

```
def ResultIter(cursor, limit=100):
    while True:
        results = cursor.fetchmany(limit)
        if not results:
            break
        for result in results:
            yield result
```

Based on this approach you can implement multithreading processing as well, but I'm really not sure about performance.